# Contar consonantes en mayúscula en una cadena de caracteres

Tags: java

en un examen de Java me pidieron contar cada vez que una cadena contenga consonantes en mayúscula. Tengo una idea mínima, pero no se como realizarlo.
Pienso que tengo que recorrer la cadena y comprobar si tiene consonantes o no y después comprobar si alguna está en mayúscula o no.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que poner lo que has hecho para poderte ayudar

Comment: Adjunta el código que tienes hecho para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

tal vez algo asi te sirva, la logica esta ahi, seria solo acomodarlo a tus necesidades, si necesitas ayuda para algo asi deberias estudiar un poco mas los metodos de las cadenas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

En vez de usar substring, podrias usar charAt();, la diferencia es que ese metodo regresa un caracter en vez de una cadena, y no se le puede hacer el matches();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena = sc.next();
    int numeroDeConsonantesMayusculas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (cadena.substring(i, i+1).matches("[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]")) {
            numeroDeConsonantesMayusculas++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Este texto tiene " + numeroDeConsonantesMayusculas + " consonantes mayusculas");
}
```